# voting public -- is "public" an adjective?

Tags: word-meaning, nouns, parts-of-speech

Example with [a context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_sovereignty_movement):

> Approximately 60% of Québec's **voting public** rejected the idea put forth by Parti Québécois leader René Lévesque.

*voting* is obviously a noun there. But how does *public* fit into the picture? Is it used as a postpositive adjective?

Comment: It is uncommon for participles to be employed as nouns in English. In this case, *public* is the noun and the participle *voting* is employed as an adjective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"public" is a noun = "the general population"

"voting" "is a present participle used as an adjective" (per [StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32)) = "the portion that is both eligible to vote and bothers to vote"

"Québec's voting public" = "the people in Québec who vote(d)"

Comment: [public](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/public?showCookiePolicy=true) is also defined as (9) "a part or section of the community grouped because of a common interest, activity, etc ". The "common thing" here being participating in the election.

Comment: +0.5. *Voting* is a present participle used as an adjective.